# First responder on mouse down behavior NSControl and NSView

Tags: swift, nsview, appkit, first-responder, nscontrol

I have a custom control. If it inherits from `NSView`, it automatically becomes the first responder when I click on it. If it inherits from `NSControl`, it does not. This difference in behavior persists, even if I override `mouseDown(with:)` and don't call super.

Code:

```
class MyControl: NSView {
  override var canBecomeKeyView: Bool      { return true }
  override var acceptsFirstResponder: Bool { return true }
  override func drawFocusRingMask()        { bounds.fill() }
  override var focusRingMaskBounds: NSRect { return bounds }

  override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    NSColor.white.set()
    bounds.fill()
  }
}
```

As you can see, I override `acceptsFirstResponder` among other methods and properties that are key view and responder related. I have also checked the `refusesFirstResponder` property. It is set to false.

1. What is the reason for this difference in behavior?
2. Is there a method or property that I can override to influence it?
3. Say I want the behavior where the view becomes the first responder when clicked and the view inherits from `NSControl`, is calling `window!.makeFirstResponder(self)` at the beginning of my mouse-down event handler a good solution or is there a better one?

Comment: Go to the documentation of `NSControl`, search for "firstresponder" and you'll find `refusesFirstResponder`. Maybe this is the method to override.

Comment: I know about that property. It is set to `false` by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property to override is `needsPanelToBecomeKey`.

> A Boolean value indicating whether the view needs its panel to become the key window before it can handle keyboard input and navigation.
>
> The default value of this property is false. Subclasses can override this property and use their implementation to determine if the view requires its panel to become the key window so that it can handle keyboard input and navigation. Such a subclass should also override acceptsFirstResponder to return true.
>
> This property is also used in keyboard navigation. It determines if a mouse click should give focus to a view—that is, make it the first responder). Some views (for example, text fields) want to receive the keyboard focus when you click in them. Other views (for example, buttons) receive focus only when you tab to them. You wouldn't want focus to shift from a textfield that has editing in progress simply because you clicked on a check box.

`NSView` returns `true`, `NSControl` returns `false`.