# Change background colour of NSTextField when renaming using ReturnKey

Tags: swift, macos, nstextfield

I have a `NSTextField` which has the background colour set as clear.

When I press enter, the textfield goes into editing mode and starts renaming the file just as `Xcode`.

Here I want to change the background colour to white. Currently, I am changing the background colour in `controlTextDidBeginEditing(_ obj: Notification)` which is called after the textfield receives a change in text.

However, I am looking for a method which can change the background colour as soon as I press enter.

Here is my current code:

```swift
private class TextField: NSTextField, NSTextFieldDelegate {
    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        delegate = self
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    public func controlTextDidBeginEditing(_ obj: Notification) {
        let textField = obj.object as! NSTextField
        textField.backgroundColor = NSColor.textBackgroundColor
    }

    public func controlTextDidEndEditing(_ obj: Notification) {
        let textField = obj.object as! NSTextField
        textField.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Ask not what `controlTextDidBeginEditing(_:)` can do for you.  Ask what you can do with `func doCommand(by aSelector: Selector!, command infoDictionary: [AnyHashable : Any]!)`.

Comment: Thanks El, I tried this method and found it is called when the textfield ends editing (by pressing the return key second time).

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand what you have said.  I only understand grammatically-correct English sentences.

Comment: No worries, thanks :).

Comment: Not related to the issue but instead of making the text field its own delegate you could override `textDidBeginEditing(_:)` and `textDidEndEditing(_:)`.

Comment: Is the text field editable/selectable or do you make it editable when the Return key is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to change the color when the text become the firstResponder (i.e when a user clicks on the textField)? If so I think you should use the [textShouldBeginEditing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextfield/1399399-textshouldbeginediting) - `func textShouldBeginEditing(_ textObject: NSText) -> Bool` and the appropriate `func control(_ control: NSControl,  textShouldBeginEditing fieldEditor: NSText) -> Bool` functions.

If I miss understand and what you actually meant is to change the background color after the user clicks the "enter" button in the keyboard that pops - you want to change the color after the textField finishes to be the firstResponder.
In this case you should use the `textShouldEndEditing` or `textDidEndEditing` delegate methods and their corresponding control methods
[textShouldEndEditing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextfield/1399434-textshouldendediting)
[textDidEndEditing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextfield/1399420-textdidendediting)

Comment: Unfortunately, `textShouldBeginEditing` and `control(_ control: NSControl,  textShouldBeginEditing fieldEditor: NSText)` are also called after receiving text input.

Comment: By pressing enter, I meant the textfield goes into editing mode and starts renaming the file just as Xcode. If I press enter again, it will exit the editing mode.

Comment: Interesting, you are right - I was not aware of this behaviour on macOS... Maybe this could help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55078226/first-responder-on-mouse-down-behavior-nscontrol-and-nsview. Unless using @El Tomato suggestion I think you will have to create a new subclass of NSTextField and use the mouse function of NSResponder to achieve what you want... or maybe use a extension? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsresponder

Comment: Thanks anyway, appreciate your time. `doCommand` is also called when editing ends.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the method to override was `selectText(_ sender: Any?)` which is called immediately when the `NSTextField` becomesFirstResponder as the text gets selected by default.

```swift
override func selectText(_ sender: Any?) {
    let textField = sender as! NSTextField
    textField.backgroundColor = NSColor.textBackgroundColor
    super.selectText(sender)
}

public func controlTextDidEndEditing(_ obj: Notification) {
    let textField = obj.object as! NSTextField
    textField.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear
}
```